# .htaccess redirect subdomain, with exceptions

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

In updating my site, I'm trying to redirect a subdomain to a static WordPress page I recently made: stories.amcorbin.com --> amcorbin.com/stories

However, I have specific pages on that subdomain, already linked elsewhere and out of my control, that I don't want to result in broken links. Example: stories.amcorbin.com/baseofthecomet.html

I managed to get the htaccess to redirect the subdomain, but I can't get it to apply the exception conditions. Here is where I am:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/images/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/baseofthecomet.html [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/digital-witnesses.html [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/inheritance.html [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/intelpost.html [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/silver.html [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/silverandgold.html [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/the-fairy-woods.html [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.amcorbin.com/stories$1 [L,R=301]

Redirect 301 stories.amcorbin.com http://amcorbin.com/stories/
```

I've done some fiddling with the RegEx, but I'm pretty shaky on this. I also thought, oh, I'll just move or copy all the pages I want to keep...except that has its own problems.

As a *complete newbie* to htaccess, I'm astonished that I've managed to get as far as I have, but I'm at my wit's end. Can anyone help me get past this last hurdle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use Redirect 301, only RewriteRule with R=301 is enough.

I see you use ^/ in your htaccess, %{REQUEST_URI} does not include the / in the beginning of this string.

So please try:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/images/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/baseofthecomet.html [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/digital-witnesses.html [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/inheritance.html [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/intelpost.html [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/silver.html [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/silverandgold.html [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/the-fairy-woods.html [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.amcorbin.com/stories/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Thank you.

Comment: In httpd.conf, REQUEST_URI does have a leading /. But in htaccess, it does not include a leading /.

Comment: Yes, you are right, but it's required in **RewriteCond** on both contexts.

Comment: You are right, in RewriteCond, it starts with a leading /.
I edited the answer. You should add a slash before $1.

Browsers remembers old 301 rules, so I think you should test it by a Private window or delete all cache and history before trying again.

Comment: Thank you both so much! The edited answer works perfectly.